# ADO.NET and SQLite single cell select performance

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite, ado.net

I want to create simple database in runtime, fill it with data from internal resource and then read each record through loop. Previously I used LiteDb for that but I couldn't squeeze time anymore so
I choosed SQLite.
I think there are few things to improve I am not aware of.

**Database creation process:**

1. First step is to create table

```
using var create = transaction.Connection.CreateCommand();
create.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE tableName (Id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, Value TEXT) WITHOUT ROWID";
create.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

2. Next insert command is defined

```
var insert = transaction.Connection.CreateCommand();
insert.CommandText = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tableName VALUES (@Id, @Record)";
var idParam = insert.CreateParameter();
var valueParam = insert.CreateParameter();
idParam.ParameterName = "@" + IdColumn;
valueParam.ParameterName = "@" + ValueColumn;
insert.Parameters.Add(idParam);
insert.Parameters.Add(valueParam);
```

3. Through loop each value is inserted

```
idParameter.Value = key;
valueParameter.Value = value.ValueAsText;
insert.Parameters["@Id"] = idParameter;
insert.Parameters["@Value"] = valueParameter;
insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

4. Transaction commit `transaction.Commit();`
5. Create index

```
using var index = transaction.Connection.CreateCommand();
index.CommandText = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_tableName ON tableName(Id);";
index.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**And after that i perform milion selects (to retrieve single value):**

```
using var command = _connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT Value FROM tableName WHERE Id = @id;";
var param = command.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@id";
param.Value = id;
command.Parameters.Add(param);
return command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult).ToString();
```

For all select's one connection is shared and never closed. Insert is quite fast (less then minute) but select's are very troublesome here. Is there a way to improve them?

Table is quite big (around ~2 milions records) and Value contains quite heavy serialized objects.
System.Data.SQLite provider is used and connection string contains this additional options: Version=3;Journal Mode=Off;Synchronous=off;

Comment: You should look into LIMIT and OFFSET to retrieve a range of multiple values for every SELECT query you make until the entire table is iterated. How many you can LIMIT at a time of depends on the size of the values since your connection could time out if it is too large.

Comment: What is the performance of select query if the table contains only tens of records?

Comment: These lines:
using var command = _connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT Value FROM tableName WHERE Id = @id;";...

Are inside a function called in a loop? Can you show "the loop" and where the id parameter in "param.Value = id;" is passed?

Comment: @david-ao The usage of Read method cannot be predicated. Sometimes it will be called over loop, sometimes just single record or small group of records. But mostly it will be foreach loop of all id's not in the same order as insert.

Comment: @olabacker It may help in specific use case but select iteration can differ from insert order. At the end it could even slow down

Comment: Before giving an answer I would need this info:
When the case is a for each loop is the order important?
You need just to just fetch all the objects or you need a specific order?
If a specific order is needed and you cannot control it: the needed order is for all objects or for group of objects? e.g. groups are unrelated but objects in same group need to be fetched in a specific sequence?

Comment: Order is not important. I just need to fetch some (or all) records.

Comment: Please share the for each loop

Answer (score 1):

If you go for **performance**, you need to consider this: **each independent SELECT command is a roundtrip to the DB with some extra costs**. It's similar to a N+1 select problem in case of parent-child relations.

The best thing you can do is to get a LIST of items (values):

```
SELECT Value FROM tableName WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, ...);
```

Here's a link on how to code that: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/116/parameterized-in-clauses-with-ado-net-and-linq

Comment: Also consider using entity framework and ORM. If set up correctly for read, it won't be much slower, and you can nicely do eager-fetch related items and also avoid typos while coding...